# Batch - How to add several variables to one variable?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have this problem that I want to add the content of one parameter to another.
So I will explain this to you. This is some of my code:

```
set /a A=%A1%+%A2%+%A3%+%A4%+%A5%+%A6%+%A7%+%A8%+%A9%
set /a B=%B1%+%B2%+%B3%+%B4%+%B5%+%B6%+%B7%+%B8%+%B9%
set /a C=%C1%+%C2%+%C3%+%C4%+%C5%+%C6%+%C7%+%C8%+%C9%
set /a D=%D1%+%D2%+%D3%+%D4%+%D5%+%D6%+%D7%+%D8%+%D9%
set TestTheAnswer= The following lines are wrong: 
if %A% NEQ 45 (then it should add "A, " to %TestTheAnswer% and of course the same with the other ones.)
echo %TestTheAnswer%
```

And at the end it should be like:
"The following lines are wrong: A, B, D ,". I have already an option how to do this in my mind but it would be very complicated...
So can anyone help me with this? :)
regards

Comment: *"I have already an option how to do this in my mind but it would be very complicated."* - Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. there are several points here; the first one is that the `set /A` command may work with just *the names* of variables, so all your variable expansions are not needed. This should work:

```
set /a A=A1+A2+A3+A4+A5+A6+A7+A8+A9
set /a B=B1+B2+B3+B4+B5+B6+B7+B8+B9
set /a C=C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6+C7+C8+C9
set /a D=D1+D2+D3+D4+D5+D6+D7+D8+D9
set "TestTheAnswer= The following lines are wrong:"
if %A% NEQ 45 set "TestTheAnswer=%TestTheAnswer% A,"
if %B% NEQ 45 set "TestTheAnswer=%TestTheAnswer% B,"
if %C% NEQ 45 set "TestTheAnswer=%TestTheAnswer% C,"
if %D% NEQ 45 set "TestTheAnswer=%TestTheAnswer% D,"
echo %TestTheAnswer:~0,-1%
```

However, a collection of variables with same name and a changing *subscript* is called "array", and the advantages of arrays is that you don't need to explicitly write each element of the array, but just write *one* element and change the subscript via a `for` command. Also, you may make good use of the fact that `set /A` command allows to perform *several* operations separating each one with a comma:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%i in (1,1,9) do set /A A+=A%%i, B+=B%%i, C+=C%%i, D+=D%%i
set "TestTheAnswer= The following lines are wrong:"
for %%v in (A B C D) do if !%%v! NEQ 45 set "TestTheAnswer=!TestTheAnswer! %%v,"
echo %TestTheAnswer:~0,-1%
```

For further details on array management in Batch files, see: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

PS - Your question is about "add several *variables* to one *variable*"; a *parameter* is a different thing. I suggest you to change the topic title.

Answer (score 0):

just add `A,` to the variable:

```
...
set "wrongs= "
if %A% NEQ 45 set "wrongs=%wrongs%A, "
if %B% NEQ 45 set "wrongs=%wrongs%B, "
if %C% NEQ 45 set "wrongs=%wrongs%C, "
if %D% NEQ 45 set "wrongs=%wrongs%D, "
echo The following lines are wrong:%wrongs%
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,9) DO SET /a A%%a=%%a * 2
SET /a total=0
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,9) DO SET /a total+=A%%a

SET a
ECHO %total%

GOTO :EOF
```

I haven't the first idea what `45` has to do with the price of fish. What you appear to be doing is totalling A1..A9, B1..B9 .. D1..D9 then doing nothing with the totals of B..D

Still, here's an easy way to do the totalling. I've set `A1`..`A9` to a set of numbers, then totalled them and displayed the total along with the values installed in A*.

HTH